# Run Batch DNS Records Check on Terminal

Tags: bash, csv, scripting, dns

Newbie Alert!
I am trying to run a DNS record query for domain records in CSV via bash script. I want to find the MX records with `host -t mx example.com` and then record/output the result an another CSV.

Stuck at the stage to get the script to run the `host -t mx$domain` command because when running `host -t mx**(space must be here)**example.com;`

What I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=, read -r domain
do
    #echo ${domain/./\.}\
    host -t mx${domain/./\.}
done < test1.csv
```

Thanks
Edit 1; Adding Sample Input and Output CSV
Input CSV

```
domain
24i.co.ke,
28feb.co.ke,
4thestatewire.co.ke,
aakenya.co.ke,
```

Expected Output

```
domain,mx
24i.co.ke,"24i.co.ke mail is handled by 20 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
24i.co.ke mail is handled by 30 aspmx3.googlemail.com.
24i.co.ke mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com."
28feb.co.ke,"28feb.co.ke mail is handled by 30 aspmx3.googlemail.com.
28feb.co.ke mail is handled by 30 aspmx5.googlemail.com.
28feb.co.ke mail is handled by 30 aspmx2.googlemail.com.
28feb.co.ke mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
28feb.co.ke mail is handled by 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
28feb.co.ke mail is handled by 20 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
28feb.co.ke mail is handled by 30 aspmx4.googlemail.com."
4thestatewire.co.ke,Host 4thestatewire.co.ke not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
aakenya.co.ke,"aakenya.co.ke mail is handled by 20 ukns1.accesskenya.com.
aakenya.co.ke mail is handled by 10 smtpin.accesskenya.com."
abacus.co.ke,
```

Comment: If the space must be there (and it must), why is it not in your script? Also, how are you planning to write stuff to "another CSV", and in what format should data be added there? If you could include a sample of your input data and your expected output in the question, this would be an *awesome* first question.  :-)

Comment: I have tried different ways to add the space, such as `host -t mx ${domain/./\.}`  and I keep getting error; `host: invalid type: domain` or not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)o.ke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your substitution, `${domain/./\.}` is probably not doing what you expect (though the result may be harmless). I can see that you've tried some debugging with an `echo` line. It would be interesting to know what you thought this substitution would achieve.

Your input file is CSV with two fields, the second one empty. I can't see anything that you would need to translate or change in that first field to make it compatible with a DNS lookup.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

file="${1:-test1.csv}"

if [[ ! -f "$file" ]]; then
    printf 'No file: %s\n' "$file" >&2
    exit 1
fi

(
  read -r header; printf '%s\n' "$header"
  while IFS=, read -r domain; do
    line="$(host -t mx "$domain" | sort | head -1)"
    printf '%s,"%s"\n' "$domain" "$line"
  done
) < "$file"
```

So...

- This takes an input file as an optional argument. If the input file (or test1.csv if none is provided) does not exist, the script exits.
- It takes the MX records for the domain, sorts them, then selects the first one. By doing this, we put the lowest-numbered (highest priority) MX.
- The while loop is in parentheses so that the header can be read from the same input stream as the loop. Note that parentheses denote a subshell, so variables set inside them will not be visible to the parts of the script outside the parentheses.
- And finally, this actually prints some output, which your sample script did not. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this oneliner:

```
awk -F, 'FNR>1{ print $1 }' < input.txt \
    | xargs -n 1 sh -c 'v="$(host -t mx $1)"; echo "$1,\"$v\""' argv0
```

Based on your input file, is reading after line 1, and using the first field (the domain) without the `,`.  The output is piped to `xargs` in where execute the command and store the value in a variable so that later can print it on your desired format `domain,"output"`

The only thing pending would be to add the first line "domain,mx" to the output.

Comment: Newbie Alert!!  So this is what  just did; I ran  `awk -f email.awk domain.txt` where email.awk is the one line you just shared and I get syntax errorss `awk: email.awk:2: awk -F, 'FNR>1{ print $1 }' < domain`
`awk: email.awk:2:         ^ invalid char ''' in expression`
`awk: email.awk:2: awk -F, 'FNR>1{ print $1 }' < domain`
`awk: email.awk:2:         ^ syntax error` Am I missing something?

Comment: first try directly in the command line and check if you get no errors, probably need to escape the `,` with something like `awk -F',' ...`

Comment: Thanks. So I removed the `,`  in `domain.txt` and ran `awk -F, 'FNR>1{ print $1 }' < domain.txt \    | xargs -n 1 sh -c 'v="$(host -t mx $1)"; echo "$1,\"$v\""' argv0` I got the error
`awk: fatal: cannot open file ` ' for reading (No such file or directory)'`

Comment: No need to remove the `,` from your file, do you understand the error you are getting? you need to run the command in the  same directory where your `domains.txt` files exists

Comment: Yes I do. Unable to open `file ' `. And yes I am running the terminal in the same directory that has the domain.txt . Thanks

Comment: Runs (no error shown) but does not print anything on terminal

Comment: verify that your input is like the one you post (with the comma at the end)

Comment: I have tried with `,` and without with same outcome. Sample file that I am using to test looks like this `24i.co.ke,`
`28feb.co.ke,`
`4thestatewire.co.ke,`
`aakenya.co.ke,`
`abacus.co.ke,`

Comment: if you find the issue please let me know, I am curious to know why is not printing, returning nothing

Comment: I got to work  work with `.csv` and not '.txt' . Thank you for your patience and help. Let me now try to tunnel the output to an output csv. Thank you @nbari

Comment: Thank you once again. I have managed to pipe the output to an output csv ---> `awk -F, 'FNR>1{ print $1 }' < test1.csv \
    | xargs -n 1 sh -c 'v="$(host -t mx $1)"; echo "$1,\"$v\""' argv0 >outtest1.csv`